# CiviCRM 4.7 contribution receipts

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, receipts

Prior to updating to CiviCRM 4.7 our customers received receipts that included:

- Membership fees with each item listed separately with a description
  and price.
- Transaction number
- Billing Name and Address
- Credit Card Information (only last four of credit card)

Also, the subject line used to reflect wether this was a receipt or an invoice.

After we installed 4.7 this information stopped displaying on the receipt. Issue here
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18027
CiviCRM 4.7.10, drupal 7.50

$contributeMode is being set to "notify" for credit card payments, which is why credit card information isn't being printed.

I'm trying to update the receipt template to work around this issue.
Can someone explain if it's correct behaviour that $contributeMode is being set to "notify" for credit card payments, or is that a bug ? What does it mean ?

Is there a(nother) way to check, in the receipt template, if a payment is not only of $contributeMode 'notify' but specifically a credit card payment ? I read 'paymentMethod' is supposed to be set - who should be setting that ?

As far as I can see, the default receipt templates in 4.7.10 don't mention 'paymentMethod' anywhere. Should they, or do I have outdated templates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been worked on, here
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18027

Comment: And it has gotten better in Civi 5.8.1 - but CC details are still missing (and the issue tracker is now closed).

Comment: Added the cc issue here https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/661